# Subclass view use superclass nib file

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, ios8

I have a view (let's say A) and its corresponding xib file. I want to make two views that subclass this view and using the same xib file with different implementation. How can I do that?

Comment: Why can't you change the xib?

Comment: I want to use the same xib, but with different implementation

Answer (score 0):

```
class SuperView: UIView {

}

class InheritedView: SuperView {
 override func awakeAfterUsingCoder(aDecoder: NSCoder) -> AnyObject? {
    if self.subviews.count == 0 {
        return loadNib()
    }
    return self
}

private func loadNib() -> InheritedView {
    return NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("SuperViewNib", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as InheritedView
}
}
```